# How to check if three numbers are guessed?

Tags: java

Hi everyone on this community.
I'm a Java newbie. This is no homework, I'm really passionate about programming and I really want to learn more. I am stuck with one exercise.

Basically I have to create a simple lottery game.
The user has to input one number from 0 to 999, a three digit number.

- If the guess is exactly the same, the prize is 10.000 $,
- If the guess is about the same (digits guessed but not in order) the
  prize is 3,000 $
- If the guess is not really the same (digits guessed == 1) the prize
  is 1,000 $.

Here's my code so far: I don't know how to deal with condition 2 and 3. Could I have some hint or comment?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a three digit number");
        int guess = input.nextInt();


        //generate number:
        int lottery = (int)(Math.random() * 1000);

        if ((guess > 999) || (guess < 100)) {
            System.out.println("The number is not a three digit number. The system will exit NOW.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        else {
            // extract digits from lottery number

            int lotteryDigit1 = lottery / 100;
            int lotteryDigits = lottery % 100;
            int lotteryDigit2 = lottery / 10;
            int lotteryDigit3 = lottery % 10;


            // extract digits from guessed number

            int guessDigit1 = guess / 100;
            int remainingDigits = guess % 100;
            int guessDigit2 = guess / 10;
            int guessDigit3 = guess % 10;

            System.out.println("The lottery number is: " + lottery);

            // check the guess:

            if (guess == lottery) {
                System.out.println("Exactly what the number was.");
            }

            else if {
                // digits guessed, but not in exact order (eg. 332 = 233)
            }

            else if {
                // only one digit is guessed (eg. 332 = 442)

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Could I have some comment on the code? Is it readable or horribly written? I really don't have a clue since I am really just new to programming. Thanks.

Comment: Why the downvoting, people?

Comment: SO is not for reviewing code; you could try codereview.stockexchange.com instead.

Comment: @GhostCat doesn't seem to be asking for review; seems to be asking for "how do I write this next bit of code?" ... though... actually, on second reading, this question seems to be doing both at the same time. Anyway, Code Review Stack Exchange will take questions which contain working code only, so the functionality would first need to be implemented.

Comment: `lotteryDigit2` and `guessDigit2` are not calculated correctly. Extract the middle digit using `lottery / 10 % 10`: a touchstone for your knowledge of operator precedence and associativity.

Comment: From your code it seems that the number to be guessed can be less than 100, but you don’t accept guesses less than 100. So in some cases it will be impossible to enter a completely correct guess. It may be OK, or the game might be too easy and too expensive in prizes paid. :-)

Comment: Your code is OK. I would drop the extra parentheses and just write `if (guess > 999 || guess < 100)`. Sometimes parenthesis are good for readability, sometimes they are bad.

Comment: @Ole V.V. thank you! Fortunately there's no shortage of virtual money.

Comment: Can you use Java collections? Put each digit of the correct number in an `ArrayList` (box it into an `Integer`), sort the list. Do the same with the guess. If the lists are equal, all the digits were guessed. The last item should be less hard: compare each digit in one number to each digit in the other; if a match is found, 1 digit was correctly guessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an array, you can count how many digits the real number and the guessed number contains, and perform comparisons with that. First make two arrays of length 10 (one slot for each digit), then increase each relevant "slot" by 1 for every digit in the real number. Do the same for the guess, and compare.

I'm recommending this approach because it will scale for guesses with 4, 5, or even 15 digits, whereas coding these checks by hand will quickly turn into a problem with lots of duplicate code.

If, for some reason, you're not allowed to use arrays, you could manually do the counting - it sounds tempting to check if each digit exists in the other set of digits, but you'll run into trouble with duplicate digits (consider 112, which, when compared to 122, would contain "all" the digits; just not in the right amounts!). This will lead to a lot of duplicate code.

It'd be something like this...

```
int matchingDigits = 0;
if ( guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit1 || guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit2 || guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit3) {
    matchingDigits++;
}
if ( guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit1 || guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit2 || guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit3) {
    matchingDigits++;
}
if ( guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit1 || guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit2 || guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit3) {
    matchingDigits++;
}
```

As you can see, it's a lot of duplicate code, and it doesn't properly handle the 112 vs 122 case. To properly handle that, you'd have to split each check apart and cross out numbers you've already "used"... which is possible, but leads to really lengthy code.

Here's how you'd do it...

```
boolean digit1Used = false;
boolean digit2Used = false;
boolean digit3Used = false;
int matchingDigits = 0;
if ( guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit1) {
    matchingDigits++;
    digit1Used = true;
} else if ( guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit2) {
    matchingDigits++;
    digit2Used = true;
} else if ( guessDigit1 == lotteryDigit3) {
    matchingDigits++;
    digit3Used = true;
}

if ( guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit1 && !digit1Used) {
    matchingDigits++;
    digit1Used = true;
} else if ( guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit2 && !digit2Used) {
    matchingDigits++;
    digit2Used = true;
} else if ( guessDigit2 == lotteryDigit3 && !digit3Used) {
    matchingDigits++;
    digit3Used = true;
}

if ( guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit1 && !digit1Used) {
    matchingDigits++;
} else if ( guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit2 && !digit2Used) {
    matchingDigits++;
} else if ( guessDigit3 == lotteryDigit3 && !digit3Used) {
    matchingDigits++;
}
```

Note that I left out the checks for `digitUsed` in the first checks and the sets for `digitUsed` for the third set of checks - because we're not going to use them anymore. As you can see, it's really long AND it's basically faking arrays. Hence why it's not recommended to do so.

Imagine that solution for a 15 digit array! It'd be (N + 1 + (N*3*N) + N + N) lines long - 15 for `digitUsed` declarations, 1 for the matching digits, 15 digit comparisons of 3 lines for 15 digits, plus 15 closing braces and 15 blank lines in between - a total of 721 lines! That's why you should use arrays for this, and not checking it by hand.

If you've learned about methods already, I suggest you put the digit matcher in a separate function; that way you can keep your digit matching logic and the result-to-prize matching logic somewhat separated.

Comment: Thank you! However this is not the correct solution. In this chapter we didn't cover arrays yet, so I suppose there are more inefficient but useful ways to perform this task.

Comment: @m.rossi Ah, I see. In that case... you could manually compare each digit with each other... but it'd be harder to do

Comment: Agree with @Pimgd that it would be harder. Remember to take into account that when comparing 232 with 323, each digit can be found in the other number, but still it’s not all the correct digits guessed. I’m not sure myself how I would go about this without arrays.

Comment: @OleV.V. see solution =/ it's super ugly

Comment: @m.rossi Once you're done, you should post it on Code Review stackexchange, we'll show you how to use arrays properly =), and you can  refer to the answers once you've learned how to use arrays!

Answer (score 0):

It’s not going to be nice code. For the second bullet, guessing all the digits but not in the right order, you may write a class like:

```
public class ThreeDigitNumber {

    int digit1;
    int digit2;
    int digit3;

    public ThreeDigitNumber(int number) {
        digit1 = number / 100;
        int remainingDigits = number % 100;
        digit2 = remainingDigits / 10;
        digit3 = remainingDigits % 10;
    }

    public int getDigit1() {
        return digit1;
    }

    public int getDigit2() {
        return digit2;
    }

    public int getDigit3() {
        return digit3;
    }

    boolean isDigitGuessed(int digit) {
        if (digit == digit1) {
            // allow digit to be guessed only once, so set to a non-digit value when returning true
            digit1 = -1;
            return true;
        }
        if (digit == digit2) {
            digit2 = -1;
            return true;
        }
        if (digit == digit3) {
            digit3 = -1;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Now you can test whether all digits have been guessed:

```
ThreeDigitNumber lotteryTdn = new ThreeDigitNumber(lottery);
ThreeDigitNumber guessTdn = new ThreeDigitNumber(guess);

boolean allDigitsGuessed = false;
if (lotteryTdn.isDigitGuessed(guessTdn.getDigit1())) {
    if (lotteryTdn.isDigitGuessed(guessTdn.getDigit2())) {
        if (lotteryTdn.isDigitGuessed(guessTdn.getDigit3())) {
            allDigitsGuessed = true; // 3000 $ won
        }
    }
}
```